# How to set Labels of RadioButtonGroup with bound Enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a `RadioButtonGroup<MyEnum>` and I set the items with an Enum. The labels of the single items are now the elements of my Enum. Because of code conventions, my Enum elements are written big. I added a `public String getText(MyEnum e)` method to my Enum and I want the labels of the RadioButtonGroup to be these texts.

I also have several ComboBoxes and their elements come from Enums, too. The ComboBoxes have a method `setItemLabelGenerator()` which I can use to set my Enum elements text presentations as labels.

My Enum

```java
public enum MyEnum{
    OPT1, OPT2, OPT3;

    public static String getText(MyEnum e) {
        switch(e) {
            case OPT1:  return "Option 1";
            case OPT2:  return "Option 2";
            case OPT3:  return "Option 3";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static Collection<MyEnum > getValues(){
        Collection<MyEnum > resultList = new ArrayList<MyEnum >();
        resultList.add(OPT1);
        resultList.add(OPT2);
        resultList.add(OPT3);
    }
}
```

In my UI class, I have my RadioButtonGroup with the Enum elements as items:

```java
RadioButtonGroup<MyEnum> myRadioGroup= new RadioButtonGroup<MyEnum>();
myRadioGroup.setItems(MyEnum.getValues());
```

Unfortunately, the labels of the items are "OPT1", "OPT2" and "OPT3" but I would like them to be "Option 1", "Option 2" and "Option 3".

For my ComboBoxes I can use `setItemLabelGenerator()` method to get nice labels:

```java
ComboBox<MyEnum> myBox= new ComboBox<MyEnum>();
myBox.setItems(MyEnum.getValues());
myBox.setItemLabelGenerator(MyEnum::getText);
```

The iteams inmy ComboBox are then "Option 1", "Option 2" and "Option 3".

Can someone tell me, how to get a result like with the ComboBoxes for RadioButtonGroups? I want my users to see nice labels in the UI :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RadioButtonGroup` does not have `setItemLabelGenerator(...)`, but you can achieve the same with `setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>(...))`.

So in this case

```
myBox.setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>(MyEnum::getText));
```

Comment: For the record, https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-radio-button-flow/issues/107 suggest adding a `setItemLabelGenerator` shorthand method.

Comment: Thanks for opening that issue, I was just thinking about doing the same

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is to do `toString` on the objects in a `ComboBox`. So why not make `toString` return what you expect, or set a label property with a getter?

```
enum MyOptions {
    OPT1("Option 1"),
    OPT2("Option 2"),
    OPT3("Option 3");

    private final String label;

    MyOptions(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    // either use getLabel as your item label generator...
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    // ...or if you don't care about printing in logs etc. 
    //    just override the default toString implementation
    public String toString() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this enum is _only_ used for UI purposes, this is an OK workaround.  If the enum is from somewhere else it a) might not be possible and b) you usually want your toString() for "developer consumption"

Comment: exactly, which is why I added the comments in the code snippets.